# weak and strong extrema for Euler-Lagrange equations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Let the curve $C:x = x(t)$ be the extremum path.

Let the curve $C': x_u= x(t) + u\eta(t)$ be the varied path(where $u$ is small).

The curve $C'$ lies in the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $C$ if $|x-x_u| < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$

and the curve $C'$ lies in the $(\epsilon,\epsilon')$-neighbourhood of $C$ if both $|x-x_u| < \epsilon$ and $|\dot{x}-\dot{x}_u| < \epsilon'$ for $\epsilon,\epsilon' > 0$

Basically a $\textbf{weak extremum}$ is found if we compare the curve $C$ to the curves in the $(\epsilon,\epsilon')$-neighbourhood, and similarly a $\textbf{strong extremum}$ is found if we compare the curve $C$ to curves is in the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood.

During the formulation of the Euler-Lagrange equations we have$I(u) = \int^b_aL(t,x(t,u),\dot{x}(t,u))dt = \int^b_aL(t,x(t) + u\eta(t),\dot{x}(t) + u\dot{\eta}(t))dt$

The taylor expansion of our functional is :$I(u) = I(0) +  u \left(\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}u}\right)_{u=0} + O(u^2)$

1. First I belive that the $u$ is small so that the $O(u^2)$ term can be dropped and thus $I(u) - I(0) =  u \left(\frac{\textrm{d}I}{\textrm{d}u}\right)_{u=0}$, allowing the terms on the LHS to have the same sign as the term on the RHS(is this the reason for the smallness of $u$?)
2. For the weak condition, I belive that the first part of the neightbourhood $|x-x_u| < \epsilon$ is only used to show that the extrema that we are trying to find are only local extremums and thus we are only comparing these neightbourhood curves(is this correct?).
3. But I don't know why or where we use the second part of the neightbourhood $|\dot{x}-\dot{x}_u| < \epsilon'$. Why do we need the curve to have this property?
4. What are the situations when we need to find the weak instead of the strong extreme values, and visa versa?

I would greatly appreciate any information you can give. I know I asked a lot of questions here, so even if you only want to answer 1 or 2 of them I will still really appreciate it.